# Unable to create an unwind segue when using multiple storyboards in a project

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, unwind-segue

I ran into an issue where I had the following setup, but was unable to get an unwind segue to work.

The storyboards were created several months ago, and were refactored from an original main storyboard to split them out into individual ones, with each storyboard having a single view controller.

The storyboards:

- MainMenu.storyboard (Contains the navigation controller)
- SubMenu.storyboard (Contains the segue that sends the user to the destination storyboard)
- Destination.storyboard (Should contain unwind segue)

In the SubMenu viewcontroller, I have the following unwind segue:

```
@IBAction func unwindToSubMenu(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

I then place a bar button item on the navigation item for the destination view controller. Attempting to link the bar button item to the exit icon on the Destination.storyboard file does not result in the unwindToSubMenu segue appearing.

Also, right clicking on the exit icon results in an empty field.

I did attempt to move the Destination.storyboard contents back to the SubMenu.storyboard to see if it had something to do with the reference links, but this was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated with a better answer.

I ran into this problem again using the latest version of XCode (8.2.1) where a properly configured segue was not appearing.

To make sure I was not insane, I first created a small sample project where I only lifted the relevant code, and was able to confirm that it was set up properly.

With that out of the way, I found a better solution to this issue by creating a garbage storyboard & associated view controller.

The view controller only contained this code:

```
class GarbageViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func unwind(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) { }
}
```

This was then set as the view controller for the garbage storyboard.

I then clicked on the exit outlet in the garbage storyboard file to confirm that the unwind method defined above appeared. Once it appeared, the unwind segue I wanted suddenly became available as well.

Comment: If i could upvote this more times.  It's astounding how much spaghetti code storyboards induce.

Comment: @Eppilo Hah, this is one case where Garbage in > Useful out works